# What is '(signal_name)' notation mean in Specman?

Tags: specman

I am new to Specman and trying to learn it by reading existing code.

I came across the following function and can't find an explanation in specman documentation...

```
VerifyNode(end_point:string, derived_value:uint) is also {
    if ('(end_point)' === ~derived_value) {
         message("Error1");
    }
    else if ('(end_point)' === derived_value) {
         message("Error2");
    }
    else {
         message("Error3");
    }

}
```

I assume logically the `'(end_point)'` is getting actual value of `end_point` signal in run-time. Is that true?

Error1 will be the message if value of `end_point` at run time is negate the `derived_value` unsigned integer.

Error2 will be the message if value of `end_point` at run time is the same as the `derived_value` unsigned integer.

How can i explain the "Error3" condition?

Comment: Notice this example uses the `===` operator (rather than the usual `==` equality operator), which, according to Specman documentation, is Verilog-style four-state comparison operator, considering also the x and z values. You'd probably want to read that part of Specman documentation, about `===`.

Answer (score 0):

`'(end_point)'` is two things.  It is old-school, non-port access to the device under test (DUT) and the `(end_point)` part of that snippet is the way to do string substitution directly in the `''` access to the DUT.  Using the old style of access to the DUT can drastically slow down simulation speed, if your design is big enough for that to be a concern for you.  Also, this methodology lacks more static compile time checks as those strings can be anything and you'll only know the path is wrong when you simulate it and the DUT path cannot be found, creating an error.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed this is the very old school of signal access based on string. I recommend you search for "simple_port".

The end_point is a string, that should be the full HDL path of the signal you want to read. Example of calling this method:

```
// check if signal has the value 3:   
VerifyNode("top.module_a.sig_val", 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The official name of '' is called the tick notation in Specman documentation.  Search for the term "tick notation" in cdnshelp and you will find it.